# Composition of a function and a value

Tags: julia

I'd like to avoid brackets in applying a composition of functions to a value. I come up with the idea to compose a function and a value:

```
julia> ∘(f::Function, x::Number)=f(x)
∘ (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> sqrt ∘ abs ∘ -2
1.4142135623730951

julia> sqrt ∘ abs ∘ (1-3)
1.4142135623730951
```

My question is how to declare the x argument to accept a "value" which is not a function, so that it does not overwrite the `∘(f::Function, g::Function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is a good idea but you could probably use this:

```bash
∘(f, g) = f(g)                                              # define for all
∘{S<:Function,T<:Function}(f::S, g::T) = (x...)->f(g(x...)) # but not for fnc
```

**edit**: I guess you don't want to redefine functionality for any subtype of Function

**edit2**: needed bigger redefinition

You don't avoid brackets though:

```bash
sqrt ∘ abs ∘ (x->2x) ∘ 1
```

Answer (score 4):

What does **compose** a function and a value mean? Might it mean scaling with a constant value? e.g. `sqrt ∘ abs ∘ x->-2x`(this gives you a function, not the result). But it seems what you would like to do is just applying the function to a value, in this case, you could write `-2 |> sqrt ∘ abs` if you really really hate brackets. I agree with you that overwrite the `∘` is not a good idea, cause it breaks the concept of function composition.

Comment: Thanks for inspirational answer! :)

Comment: Thanks. I see `-2 |> sqrt ∘ abs` is a better option, no hack.

Comment: @Phuoc you could consider `-2 |> abs |> sqrt` too.

Comment: @Gnimuc How about compose a function and a constant function. A value can be thought of as a constant function `x->a_const_value`

Comment: @Phuoc then you'll still get a function, a pretty wired one,  it'll always return the same value by whatever args you call it with. In this case, I'd rather pre-calculate the result and make it a `const`, but I guess your method does have some specific use cases.